# Find the distance from F (foci) to the point on the ellipse with the largest y -coordinate.

Tags: geometry

Have to use:
$x^2/a^2 + y^2/(a^2-c^2)=1$

I got y-coordinate to be $\sqrt{a^2-c^2} $  And the distance to be $d=a$.
I hope this is correct.

Comment: Your expression should only involve $a$ and $c$, not $x$ or $y$ which are variables. You are right that the highest point has $x=0$; can you solve your ellipse equation for $y$ after setting $x=0$?

Comment: With Pythagoras theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

We have

$$y^2=\frac{a^2-c^2}{a^2}(a^2-x^2)$$

which is the largest when $x$ is as small as possible.

Comment: I got y= square root of a^2-c^2 when x=0.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The largest $y$-coordinate is $\sqrt{a^2-c^2}$ and the smallest $y$-coordinate is $-\sqrt{a^2-c^2}$

Comment: Is the distance then d= a?

Comment: @jim What is $d$? What distance?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant distance=a

Comment: @jim I don't understand your question. Which distance (between what) you are considering?